# React.UseEffect() hook with comparision in dependency array

Tags: react-hooks, hook, use-effect

I was wondering if it possible to compare dependency in useEffect in dependency array. So, that I do not need to check again.

I need to run some code only if **props.flag === true**. Can we write it like this?

```
useEffect(()=>{
 DoSomething();
},[props.flag === true]);
```

Comment: Is the flag a boolean? You could push the logic down from the parent, then when the boolean props change the use effect will be called on just `props.flag`. If you need to check the value for true/false, check it within the `useEffect`, e.g. `if (props.flag) {...}`.

Comment: Yes, but is this possible to check this condition in dependency array ? and go inside the useEffect hook iff condition is true. 
Let say if I do not want to add extra check inside my hook.